# Read and Write to an XML

Tags: c#, encryption, xml-serialization

I have 2 methods as shown below which read and write to my XML file. What is the easiest method to encrypt the XML file and allow read/write of it from my code ?

**Read XML File**

```
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ItemsUnderControlObject>));
// Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()) + @"\itemlist.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

// Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl = (List<ItemsUnderControlObject>)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
// Cleanup
ReadFileStream.Close();
```

**Write XML File**

```
// Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class
 XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ItemsUnderControlObject>));
// Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()) + @"\itemlist.xml");
SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

Comment: take a look at this http://srinivasganaparthi.blogspot.com/2011/04/encrypt-and-decrypt-xml-file-in-c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace that provides a bunch of classes that let you encrypt/decrypt.  Many will take a stream to en/decrypt, so just pass your WriteFileStream/ReadFileStream instances to a crypto class, and that'll do it.

The example below is based in part on [example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on set up of AES crypto provider (and can be adapted for other crypto algorithms).  It requires some initialization code that would be dependent on your implementation - [see example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there.

```
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (Stream msEncrypt = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString()) + @"\itemlist.xml"))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        // Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class
                        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ItemsUnderControlObject>));
                        // Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
                        SerializerObj.Serialize(swEncrypt, MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

- Code is best effort - don't have means to build it at the moment.  So may need a bit of TLC...  But should give a pretty good idea of what's needed.

Comment: i want to encrypt MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl - is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is. create encryption stream using one of the classes in aforementioned namespace, and pass to it your WriteFileStream.

Comment: Could you please give a code sample of how to do this based on my code above ?

Comment: @user1438082 Done, see example though may need a bit of adaptation and correction (aka TLC)